# Sum of matrixes in PHP and table displaying?

Tags: php, html, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to implement the sum of two **multidimensional arrays** in **PHP**, however, by using `foreach` I really get lost among the *indexes* of the two m-dimensions arrays I'm managing.

How can I access to both arrays properly?

```
function sumaMatriz($matrix1, $matrix2){
            echo "<table width=\"200\" border=\"1\">";

            foreach($matrix1 as $row1 =>$rValue1){
                foreach ($matrix2 as $row2 => $rValue2) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    foreach($rValue1 as $col1 =>$cValue1){
                        foreach ($rValue2 as $col2 => $cValue2) {
                            echo "<td>".$cValue1+$cValue2."</td>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
            echo "</table>";
}
```

I define `$m1` and `$m2` this way:

```
$m1 = array (array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
         array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
         array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
         array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100))
        );


$m2 = array (array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
         array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
         array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
         array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100))
        );
```

This is my *output*, first two displayed arrays are the inputs to the function. The last table is the problematic one, it's showing up as a single row.

[image: What I'm getting]

So the resulting HTML is the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        Novatos del PHP
        </title>
    </head>

    <body> <center>



    <h2>Matriz 1</h2><table width="200" border="1"><tr><td>58</td><td>49</td><td>90</td></tr><tr><td>83</td><td>70</td><td>13</td></tr><tr><td>21</td><td>1</td><td>69</td></tr><tr><td>56</td><td>73</td><td>39</td></tr></table><br><h2>Matriz 2</h2><table width="200" border="1"><tr><td>31</td><td>35</td><td>86</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>86</td><td>99</td></tr><tr><td>98</td><td>16</td><td>40</td></tr><tr><td>99</td><td>35</td><td>1</td></tr></table><br><h2>Suma de matrices</h2><table width="200" border="1"><tr>31</td>35</td>86</td>31</td>35</td>86</td>31</td>35</td>86</td></tr><tr>2</td>86</td>99</td>2</td>86</td>99</td>2</td>86</td>99</td></tr><tr>98</td>16</td>40</td>98</td>16</td>40</td>98</td>16</td>40</td></tr><tr>99</td>35</td>1</td>99</td>35</td>1</td>99</td>35</td>1</td></tr><tr>31</td>35</td>86</td>31</td>35</td>86</td>31</td>35</td>86</td></tr><tr>2</td>86</td>99</td>2</td>86</td>99</td>2</td>86</td>99</td></tr><tr>98</td>16</td>40</td>98</td>16</td>40</td>98</td>16</td>40</td></tr><tr>99</td>35</td>1</td>99</td>35</td>1</td>99</td>35</td>1</td></tr><tr>31</td>35</td>86</td>31</td>35</td>86</td>31</td>35</td>86</td></tr><tr>2</td>86</td>99</td>2</td>86</td>99</td>2</td>86</td>99</td></tr><tr>98</td>16</td>40</td>98</td>16</td>40</td>98</td>16</td>40</td></tr><tr>99</td>35</td>1</td>99</td>35</td>1</td>99</td>35</td>1</td></tr><tr>31</td>35</td>86</td>31</td>35</td>86</td>31</td>35</td>86</td></tr><tr>2</td>86</td>99</td>2</td>86</td>99</td>2</td>86</td>99</td></tr><tr>98</td>16</td>40</td>98</td>16</td>40</td>98</td>16</td>40</td></tr><tr>99</td>35</td>1</td>99</td>35</td>1</td>99</td>35</td>1</td></tr></table>

     </center> </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You haven't described which part is not working...

Comment: Well, @JuanMendes that's inserting *into* the table. It prints values outside before the table, as seen in picture.

Comment: Can you post the resulting HTML? Maybe even show the contents of `$matrix1,$matrix2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested:

```
function sumaMatriz($matrix1, $matrix2){
            echo "<table width=\"200\" border=\"1\">";

            foreach($matrix1 as $row1 =>$rValue1){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    foreach($rValue1 as $col1 =>$cValue1)
                            echo "<td>".($cValue1+$matrix2[$row1][$col1])."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
}
```

The basic idea is that you should only have at most 2 loops: one for the rows, and columns. If $row1 and $col1 are numeric indices, then you should be able to use these to directly access the values within $matrix2 as well.

If this doesn't work then post how you are defining/setting $matrix1 and $matrix2.

Comment: Not working @Matt, I posted the `$matrix1` and `$matrix2` definitions.

Comment: Ok try that. It needed parentheses around the sum.

Comment: @Diego Just so it's clear to the OP, there are two problems, your algorithm was wrong, but the string concatenation was wrong too, adding the parentheses makes it do what you expected in the first place

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're seeing right now is because of the string concatenation mixed with integer addition. If you use the following, you'll see numbers in your table, but I think your algorithm is incorrect.

```
//  Make sure integer addition happens before concatenation
echo "<td>". ($cValue1+$cValue2) ."</td>"
```